# Не загружается изображение: нарушение прав доступа при чтении

Tags: изображения, directx, bitmap

Начал изучать д2д1 и уже напоролся на проблему.

```
void LoadBitmapFromFile(ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* d2drenderr)
{
HRESULT hr;
IWICImagingFactory* d2dWICFactory = NULL;
IWICBitmapDecoder* d2dDecoder = NULL;
IWICFormatConverter* d2dConverter = NULL;
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* d2drender = d2drenderr;
IWICBitmapFrameDecode* d2dBmpSrc = NULL;
ID2D1Bitmap* d2dBmp = NULL;

RECT rc = {0,0,800,600};

D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                __uuidof(IWICImagingFactory), (void**)(&d2dWICFactory));

hr = d2dWICFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(L"1.png", NULL, GENERIC_READ,
                                    WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, &d2dDecoder);

hr = d2dWICFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&d2dConverter);

hr = d2dDecoder->GetFrame(0, &d2dBmpSrc);

hr = d2dConverter->Initialize(d2dBmpSrc, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
            WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0.f,          WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut);

hr = d2drender->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(d2dConverter, NULL, &d2dBmp);
}
```

Каждый раз одна и та же ошибка -

```
Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x000000013F5C574A в Проект1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x0000000000000000.
```

на смотрите на то, что битмап внутри функции и у меня к нему нет доступа. Раньше всё выглядело по-другому и он был в аргументах как двойной указатель, просто сейчас для меня это не принципиально, он просто не загружается, где бы я его не объявил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: До этого делал всё в точности как http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKZvT4U71rg

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке довольно ясное: вы пытаетесь обратиться к нулевому адресу.  Это означает, что вы передаете в какую-то функцию нулевой указатель, что нельзя делать.